# Reinstalling windows 10 on a machine with more than one HDD

Tags: windows-10

So, I wish to use the built-in method of windows 10 to remove and everything and start clean but I am wondering the following, choosing to remove all data and wipe, would wipe the main hdd in which Windows is installed or will it do it for all?

Comment: When i doubt, disconnect other drives before installation.

Comment: Would wipe the main hdd in which Windows is installed or will it do it for all? - It will wipe the main HDD (won't touch other HDD)

Comment: @Madhubala answer please

Comment: If you are sure of this put it as an answer not a comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Media Creation link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

This will allow you to:

(a) Keep Nothing (new install)

(b) Keep Data (what is says - no applications kept)

(c) Keep All. The latter keeps everything and is a good overall repair tool.

Using this method will install (repair) Windows 10 on the disk it was resident on. It does not install on all disks, just the one.

This is a good way to go.

If you wish to wipe the disk (format it and install) then use the Windows 10 ISO file and use that. I would be inclined to remove the second disk temporarily but it still should stick to the one disk Windows is installed on

Comment: Not an answer to my question but an alternative. So keep nothing in this case will only wipe the one disk

Comment: It will only reinstall on the one disk..  I edited my answer to include a fresh install

Answer (score 1):

`Would wipe the main hdd in which Windows is installed or will it do it for all?` - It will wipe the main HDD (won't touch other HDD)